# Recursively update rows based on foreign keys

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL 12 database with a largely hierarchical design. The tables are related something along these lines: study -> group -> subject -> sample -> assay -> measurements. One study can have several groups, which in turn can have several subjects and so on.

```
CREATE TABLE studies(study INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, is_secret BOOLEAN);

CREATE TABLE groups("group" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, study INTEGER REFERENCES studies(study) ON DELETE CASCADE, is_secret BOOLEAN;

CREATE TABLE subjects(subject INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, group INTEGER REFERENCES groups("group") ON DELETE CASCADE, is_secret BOOLEAN;

...
```

Now I would like to set `is_secret` for a given study in the `studies` table and let is cascade to all dependent entries. Exactly the same as with `ON DELETE CASCADE`, but setting this column value instead. Is there a way to do that? Thanks!

EDIT: I forgot an important piece of evidence. This has to be done without explicitly stating the relationships between tables. It should "follow the primary keys". Also, it should be possible to trigger also when `is_secret` is already `TRUE` in `studies` (to update when there is new data).

EDIT2: It should be possible to set this property not only for studies, but also for individual groups, subjects and so on (and let is cascade). It's the general mimic-on-*-cascade behavior that I'm after. Maybe one could do a delete, somehow get the affected rows, rollback and then set is_secret for those rows?

Comment: Your requests indicates the column IS_SECRET not independent in tables groups and subjects but are the value from studies. Thus they are just repeated data and should not be in those tables. For groups and subjects follow the FKs to studies. If you do not want to constantly run the joins the create a view that contains is_private.

Comment: Thanks, but see comment below and edit in OP.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to stay normalized and *not* store `is_secret` on each dependent object.

Rather, store it only in `studies`, and whenever you want to know if a dependent table is secret, you join it with its study. Such joins will be executed as efficient nested loop joins and won't slow you down considerably.

If you need that last little bit of query performance so badly that you need to denormalize in the way you suggested, define a trigger on `studies` that modifies all dependent objects. In that case, you will trade query performance for data modification performance.

Comment: True, but this is not for performance but to allow for row-level security. The database is already normalized. Those joins are fine for normal use (which is how it works now), but not so fun to do for 2000 M rows for every query that involves the large `measurements` table to check for row security.

Comment: That need not be. If you use `EXISTS (...)` in your policy, PostgreSQL may well transform it into an efficient join. Test with `EXPLAIN`!

Comment: Thanks, but it would get messy. I've skipped a couple of levels in the OP for simplicity, and this is just a small subset of the db. Also note that it's not only about the top-level study, any level of the hierarchy should cascade down. But I could possibly skip it on the lowest level where 99% of the data is.

Anyways, I found https://github.com/trlorenz/PG-recursively_delete, which I can probably adapt to my purpose.